# Annotation Processor for Jersey annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, annotations, jersey

I am just curious to know about annotation processor for Jersey annotations like for `@Path` , `@Consumes` etc .  I mean, would that be provided by `Jersey API` or by `javax.ws.rs-api-xxx.jar`?

I can't seem to figure out as how these REST annotations get processed and can I find that out by exploring code.

Clicking on `@Path` takes me its definition but I need to know the logic that processes this annotation.

I am using Eclipse and project specific annotations are not enabled.

My rest resources work perfectly when deployed in tomcat so that means annotations are getting processed by some processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are easy to process, without the need for any special processor. For example with the `@Path`, you can simply do something like

```
@Path("orders")
public class OrdersResource {}

Path annotationInstance = OrdersResource.class.getAnnotation(Path.class);
String pathValue = annotationInstance.value();
```

Mainly the thing to take away from this is that generally you get the instance of the annotation from doing some [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Then just call the methods on the annotation to get any values to process, or just check for [marker annotations](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/MarkerAnnotations.htm) to do some processing.

When Jersey processes the resource classes, it builds an internal model using the annotations. In psuedo-code it might look something like

```
@Path("orders")
public class OrdersResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String get() {}
}

Path anno = OrdersResource.class.getAnnotation(Path.class);
String path = anno.value();
Resource resource = new Resource(path);

Method[] methods = OrdersResource.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method: methods) {
    Annotation[] methodAnnos = method.getAnnotations();
    if (arrayContains(methodAnnos, (@GET, @POST, @PUT, etc)) {
        String httpMethod = getMethod(methodAnnos);
        ResourceMethod resourceMethod = new ResourceMethod(httpMethod);
        Produces producesAnno = method.getAnnotation(Produces.class);
        if (produces != null) {
            resourceMethod.setProduces(producesAnno.value());
        }
        resource.addResourceMethod(resourceMethod);
    }
}
```

With this resource model, Jersey uses it to process request.

Now the above was all pseudo code. The reflection code is real, but the APIs for the `Resource` and `ResourceMethod` are imaginary. But Jersey really has those classes, that it uses to model the resources. For example you can do

```
Resource resource = Resource.from(OrdersResource.class);
```

Just like that, we have the model. With the model we can do

```
String path = resource.getPath();
ResourceMethod method = resource.getResourceMethods();
```

**See Also:** [Introspecting Jersey resource model Jersey 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29654883/2587435) for some more explanation of how to introspect the model.

As far as the exact implementation of *how* the annotations are processed when you do say `Resource resource = Resource.from(OrdersResource.class)`. I think that is internal private stuff. I don't know if that is exposed. But it almost surely uses reflection. The only other way would be to introspect the byte code. I don't think that is how it is done (though don't quote me).

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon jersey version, when your deployment descriptor loads jersey servlet, then the servlet scans for resources and internally servlet calls ResourceConfig and all the annotation processing is done.  For example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myproject.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Now based on above web.xml, the springServlet scans all resources. Then it calls ResourceConfig and that is where all annotations like path etc is taken care:

```
/**
 * The resource configuration for configuring a web application.
 */
public abstract class ResourceConfig extends Application implements FeaturesAndProperties {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(ResourceConfig.class.getName());


    public static final String FEATURE_NORMALIZE_URI 
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.NormalizeURI";


    public static final String FEATURE_CANONICALIZE_URI_PATH 
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.CanonicalizeURIPath";


    public static final String FEATURE_REDIRECT 
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect";


    public static final String FEATURE_MATCH_MATRIX_PARAMS 
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.IgnoreMatrixParams";


    public static final String FEATURE_TRACE
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace";


    public static final String FEATURE_TRACE_PER_REQUEST
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.TracePerRequest";


    public static final String PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.property.MediaTypeMappings";


    public static final String PROPERTY_LANGUAGE_MAPPINGS
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.property.LanguageMappings";


    public static final String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_COMPONENT_PROVIDER_FACTORY_CLASS
            = "com.sun.jersey.config.property.DefaultResourceComponentProviderFactoryClass";


    public static final String PROPERTY_CONTAINER_NOTIFIER = 
            "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerNotifier";

    public static final String PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS = 
            "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters";

    /**
     * If set the list of {@link ContainerResponseFilter} that are applied
     * to filter the response. When applying the list of response filters to
     * a response each response filter is applied, in order, from the first to
     * the last entry in the list.
     * <p>
     * The instance may be a String[] or String that contains one or more fully
     * qualified class name of a request filter class separated by ';', ','
     * or ' ' (space).
     * Otherwise the instance may be List containing instances of String,
     * String[], Class&lt;? extends ContainerResponseFilter;&gt; or instances
     * of ContainerResponseFilter.
     * <p>
     * If a String[] or String of fully qualified class names or a Class then
     * each class is instantiated as a singleton. Thus, if there is more than one
     * class registered for this property or the same class is also registered for
     * the {@link #PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS} property then only
     * one instance will be instatiated.
     *
     * @see com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS = 
            "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters";

    /**
     * If set the list of {@link ResourceFilterFactory} that are applied
     * to resources. When applying the list of resource filters factories to a
     * request each resource filter factory is applied, in order, from the first
     * to last entry in the list.
     * <p>
     * The instance may be a String[] or String that contains one or more fully
     * qualified class name of a response filter class separated by ';', ','
     * or ' ' (space).
     * Otherwise the instance may be List containing instances of String,
     * String[], Class&lt;? extends ResourceFilterFactory;&gt; or instances
     * of ResourceFilterFactory.
     * <p>
     * If a String[] or String of fully qualified class names or a Class then
     * each class is instantiated as a singleton. Thus, if there is more than one
     * class registered for this property one instance will be instatiated.
     * 
     * @see com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_RESOURCE_FILTER_FACTORIES =
            "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters";

    /**
     * If set the wadl generator configuration that provides a {@link WadlGenerator}.
     * <p>
     * The type of this property must be a subclass or an instance of a subclass of
     * {@link com.sun.jersey.api.wadl.config.WadlGeneratorConfig}.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * If this property is not set the default wadl generator will be used for generating wadl.
     * </p>
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_WADL_GENERATOR_CONFIG = 
            "com.sun.jersey.config.property.WadlGeneratorConfig";

    /**
     * Common delimiters used by various properties.
     */
    public static final String COMMON_DELIMITERS = " ,;";

    /**
     * Get the map of features associated with the Web application.
     *
     * @return the features.
     *         The returned value shall never be null.
     */
    public abstract Map<String, Boolean> getFeatures();

    /**
     * Get the value of a feature.
     *
     * @param featureName the feature name.
     * @return true if the feature is present and set to true, otherwise false
     *         if the feature is present and set to false or the feature is not 
     *         present.
     */
    public abstract boolean getFeature(String featureName);

    /**
     * Get the map of properties associated with the Web application.
     *
     * @return the properties.
     *         The returned value shall never be null.
     */
    public abstract Map<String, Object> getProperties();

    /**
     * Get the value of a property.
     *
     * @param propertyName the property name.
     * @return the property, or null if there is no property present for the
     *         given property name.
     */
    public abstract Object getProperty(String propertyName);

    /**
     * Get a map of file extension to media type. This is used to drive 
     * URI-based content negotiation such that, e.g.:
     * <pre>GET /resource.atom</pre>
     * <p>is equivalent to:</p>
     * <pre>GET /resource
     *Accept: application/atom+xml</pre>
     * <p>
     * The default implementation returns an empty map.
     *
     * @return a map of file extension to media type
     */
    public Map<String, MediaType> getMediaTypeMappings() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    /**
     * Get a map of file extension to language. This is used to drive 
     * URI-based content negotiation such that, e.g.:
     * <pre>GET /resource.english</pre>
     * <p>is equivalent to:</p>
     * <pre>GET /resource
     *Accept-Language: en</pre>
     * <p>
     * The default implementation returns an empty map.
     * 
     * @return a map of file extension to language
     */
    public Map<String, String> getLanguageMappings() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    /**
     * Get a map of explicit root resource classes and root resource singleton
     * instances. The default lifecycle for root resource class instances is
     * per-request.
     * <p>
     * The root resource path template is declared using the key in the map. This
     * is a substitute for the declaration of a {@link Path} annotation on a root
     * resource class or singleton instance. The key has the same semantics as the
     * {@link Path#value() }. If such a {@link Path} annotation is present
     * it will be ignored.
     * <p>
     * For example, the following will register two root resources, first
     * a root resource class at the path "class" and a root resource singleton
     * at the path "singleton":
     * <blockquote><pre>
     *     getExplicitRootResources().put("class", RootResourceClass.class);
     *     getExplicitRootResources().put("singleton", new RootResourceSingleton());
     * </pre></blockquote>
     *
     * @return a map of explicit root resource classes and root resource 
     *         singleton instances.
     */
    public Map<String, Object> getExplicitRootResources() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    /**
     * Validate the set of classes and singletons.
     * <p>
     * A registered class is removed from the set of registered classes
     * if an instance of that class is a member of the set of registered
     * singletons.
     * <p>
     * A registered class that is an interface or an abstract class
     * is removed from the registered classes.
     * <p>
     * File extension to media type and language mappings in the properties
     * {@link #PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS} and {@link #PROPERTY_LANGUAGE_MAPPINGS},
     * respectively, are processed and key/values pairs added to the maps
     * returned from {@link #getMediaTypeMappings() } and 
     * {@link #getLanguageMappings() }, respectively. The characters of file
     * extension values will be contextually encoded according to the set of 
     * valid characters defined for a path segment.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the set of registered singletons 
     *         contains more than one instance of the same root resource class,
     *         or validation of media type and language mappings failed.
     */
    public void validate() {
        // Remove any registered classes if instances exist in registered 
        // singletons
        Iterator<Class<?>> i = getClasses().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Class<?> c = i.next();
            for (Object o : getSingletons()) {
                if (c.isInstance(o)) {
                    i.remove();
                    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, 
                            "Class " + c.getName() + 
                            " is ignored as an instance is registered in the set of singletons");                    
                }
            }            
        }

        // Find conflicts
        Set<Class<?>> objectClassSet = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        Set<Class<?>> conflictSet = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        for (Object o : getSingletons()) {
            if (o.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
                if (objectClassSet.contains(o.getClass())) {
                    conflictSet.add(o.getClass());
                } else {
                    objectClassSet.add(o.getClass());
                }
            }
        }

        if (!conflictSet.isEmpty()) {
            for (Class<?> c : conflictSet) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, 
                        "Root resource class " + c.getName() + 
                        " is instantiated more than once in the set of registered singletons");
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The set of registered singletons contains " +
                    "more than one instance of the same root resource class");
        }

        // parse and validate mediaTypeMappings set thru PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS property
        parseAndValidateMappings(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS,
                getMediaTypeMappings(), new TypeParser<MediaType>() {
            public MediaType valueOf(String value) {
                return MediaType.valueOf(value);
            }
        });

        // parse and validate language mappings set thru PROPERTY_LANGUAGE_MAPPINGS property
        parseAndValidateMappings(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_LANGUAGE_MAPPINGS,
                getLanguageMappings(), new TypeParser<String>() {
            public String valueOf(String value) {
                return LanguageTag.valueOf(value).toString();
            }
        });

        // encode key values of mediaTypeMappings and languageMappings maps
        encodeKeys(getMediaTypeMappings());
        encodeKeys(getLanguageMappings());
    }

    private interface TypeParser<T> {
        public T valueOf(String s);
    }

    private <T> void parseAndValidateMappings(String property,
            Map<String, T> mappingsMap, TypeParser<T> parser) {
        Object mappings = getProperty(property);
        if (mappings == null)
            return;

        if (mappings instanceof String) {
            parseMappings(property, (String) mappings, mappingsMap, parser);
        } else if (mappings instanceof String[]) {
            final String[] mappingsArray = (String[])mappings;
            for (int i = 0; i < mappingsArray.length; i++)
                parseMappings(property, mappingsArray[i], mappingsMap, parser);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided " + property +
                    " mappings is invalid. Acceptable types are String" +
                    " and String[].");
        }
    }

    private <T> void parseMappings(String property, String mappings,
            Map<String, T> mappingsMap, TypeParser<T> parser) {
        if (mappings == null)
            return;

        String[] records = mappings.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            String[] record = records[i].split(":");
            if (record.length != 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided " + property +
                        " mapping \"" + mappings + "\" is invalid. It " +
                        "should contain two parts, key and value, separated by ':'.");

            String trimmedSegment = record[0].trim();
            String trimmedValue = record[1].trim();

            if (trimmedSegment.length() == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The key in " + property +
                        " mappings record \"" + records[i] + "\" is empty.");
            if (trimmedValue.length() == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value in " + property +
                        " mappings record \"" + records[i] + "\" is empty.");

            mappingsMap.put(trimmedSegment, parser.valueOf(trimmedValue));
        }
    }

    private <T> void encodeKeys(Map<String, T> map) {
        Map<String, T> tempMap = new HashMap<String, T>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, T> entry : map.entrySet())
            tempMap.put(UriComponent.contextualEncode(entry.getKey(), UriComponent.Type.PATH_SEGMENT), entry.getValue());
        map.clear();
        map.putAll(tempMap);
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of root resource classes.
     * <p>
     * A root resource class is a registered class that is annotated with
     * Path.
     * 
     * @return the set of root resource classes.
     */
    public Set<Class<?>> getRootResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();

        for (Class<?> c : getClasses()) {
            if (isRootResourceClass(c))
                s.add(c);
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of provider classes.
     * <p>
     * A provider class is a registered class that is not annotated with
     * Path.
     * 
     * @return the set of provider classes.
     */
    public Set<Class<?>> getProviderClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();

        for (Class<?> c : getClasses()) {
            if (!isRootResourceClass(c))
                s.add(c);
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of root resource singleton instances.
     * <p>
     * A root resource singleton instance is a registered instance whose class
     * is annotated with Path.
     * 
     * @return the set of root resource singleton instances.
     */
    public Set<Object> getRootResourceSingletons() {
        Set<Object> s = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();

        for (Object o : getSingletons()) {
            if (isRootResourceClass(o.getClass()))
                s.add(o);
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of provider singleton instances.
     * <p>
     * A provider singleton instances is a registered instance whose class
     * is not annotated with Path.
     * 
     * @return the set of provider singleton instances.
     */
    public Set<Object> getProviderSingletons() {
        Set<Object> s = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();

        for (Object o : getSingletons()) {
            if (!isRootResourceClass(o.getClass()))
                s.add(o);
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a class is a root resource class.
     *
     * @param c the class.
     * @return true if the class is a root resource class, otherwise false
     *         (including if the class is null).
     */
    public static boolean isRootResourceClass(Class<?> c) {
        if (c == null)
            return false;

        if (c.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) return true;

        for (Class i : c.getInterfaces())
            if (i.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a class is a provider class.
     *
     * @param c the class.
     * @return true if the class is a provider class, otherwise false
     *         (including if the class is null)
     */
    public static boolean isProviderClass(Class<?> c) {
        return c != null && c.isAnnotationPresent(Provider.class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of container request filters.
     * <p>
     * This list may be modified to add or remove filter elements.
     * See {@link #PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS} for the valid elements
     * of the list.
     *
     * @return the list of container request filters.
     *         An empty list will be returned if no filters are present.
     */
    public List getContainerRequestFilters() {
        return getFilterList(PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS);
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of container response filters.
     * <p>
     * This list may be modified to add or remove filter elements.
     * See {@link #PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS} for the valid elements
     * of the list.
     *
     * @return the list of container response filters.
     *         An empty list will be returned if no filters are present.
     */
    public List getContainerResponseFilters() {
        return getFilterList(PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS);
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of resource filter factories.
     * <p>
     * This list may be modified to add or remove filter elements.
     * See {@link #PROPERTY_RESOURCE_FILTER_FACTORIES} for the valid elements
     * of the list.
     *
     * @return the list of resource filter factories.
     *         An empty list will be returned if no filters are present.
     */
    public List getResourceFilterFactories() {
        return getFilterList(PROPERTY_RESOURCE_FILTER_FACTORIES);
    }

    private List getFilterList(String propertyName) {
        final Object o = getProperty(propertyName);
        if (o == null) {
            final List l = new ArrayList();
            getProperties().put(propertyName, l);
            return l;
        } else if (o instanceof List) {
            return (List)o;
        } else {
            final List l = new ArrayList();
            l.add(o);
            getProperties().put(propertyName, l);
            return l;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the properties and features given a map of entries.
     *
     * @param entries the map of entries. All entries are added as properties.
     * Properties are only added if an existing property does not currently exist.
     *
     * Any entry with a value that is an instance of Boolean is added as a
     * feature with the feature name set to the entry name and the feature value
     * set to the entry value. Any entry with a value that is an instance String
     * and is equal (ignoring case and white space) to "true" or "false" is added
     * as a feature with the feature name set to the entry name and the feature
     * value set to the Boolean value of the entry value. Features are only added
     * if an existing feature does not currently exist.
     */
    public void setPropertiesAndFeatures(Map<String, Object> entries) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : entries.entrySet()) {
            if (!getProperties().containsKey(e.getKey())) {
                getProperties().put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }

            if (!getFeatures().containsKey(e.getKey())) {
                Object v = e.getValue();
                if (v instanceof String) {
                    String sv = ((String)v).trim();
                    if (sv.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        getFeatures().put(e.getKey(), true);
                    } else if (sv.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                        getFeatures().put(e.getKey(), false);
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof Boolean) {
                    getFeatures().put(e.getKey(), (Boolean)v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the state of an {@link Application} to this instance.
     *
     * @param app the application.
     */
    public void add(Application app) {
        if (app.getClasses() != null)
            addAllFirst(getClasses(), app.getClasses());
        if (app.getSingletons() != null)
            addAllFirst(getSingletons(), app.getSingletons());

        if (app instanceof ResourceConfig) {
            ResourceConfig rc = (ResourceConfig)app;

            getExplicitRootResources().putAll(rc.getExplicitRootResources());

            getLanguageMappings().putAll(rc.getLanguageMappings());
            getMediaTypeMappings().putAll(rc.getMediaTypeMappings());

            getFeatures().putAll(rc.getFeatures());
            getProperties().putAll(rc.getProperties());
        }
    }

    private <T> void addAllFirst(Set<T> a, Set<T> b) {
        Set<T> x = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
        x.addAll(b);
        x.addAll(a);

        a.clear();
        a.addAll(x);
    }

    /**
     * Clone this resource configuration.
     * <p>
     * The set of classes, set of singletons, map of explicit root resources,
     * map of language mappings, map of media type mappings, map of features and
     * map of properties will be cloned.
     *
     * @return a cloned instance of this resource configuration.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"CloneDoesntCallSuperClone", "CloneDoesntDeclareCloneNotSupportedException"})
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig clone() {
        ResourceConfig that = new DefaultResourceConfig();

        that.getClasses().addAll(this.getClasses());
        that.getSingletons().addAll(this.getSingletons());

        that.getExplicitRootResources().putAll(this.getExplicitRootResources());

        that.getLanguageMappings().putAll(this.getLanguageMappings());
        that.getMediaTypeMappings().putAll(this.getMediaTypeMappings());

        that.getFeatures().putAll(this.getFeatures());
        that.getProperties().putAll(this.getProperties());

        return that;
    }

    /**
     * Get a canonical array of String elements from a String array
     * where each entry may contain zero or more elements separated by ';'.
     *
     * @param elements an array where each String entry may contain zero or more
     *        ';' separated elements.
     * @return the array of elements, each element is trimmed, the array will
     *         not contain any empty or null entries.
     */
    public static String[] getElements(String[] elements) {
        // keeping backwards compatibility
        return getElements(elements, ";");
    }

    /**
     * Get a canonical array of String elements from a String array
     * where each entry may contain zero or more elements separated by characters
     * in delimiters string.
     *
     * @param elements an array where each String entry may contain zero or more
     *        delimiters separated elements.
     * @param delimiters string with delimiters, every character represents one
     *        delimiter.
     * @return the array of elements, each element is trimmed, the array will
     *         not contain any empty or null entries.
     */
    public static String[] getElements(String[] elements, String delimiters) {
        List<String> es = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (String element : elements) {
            if (element == null) continue;
            element = element.trim();
            if (element.length() == 0) continue;
            for (String subElement : getElements(element, delimiters)) {
                if (subElement == null || subElement.length() == 0) continue;
                es.add(subElement);
            }
        }
        return es.toArray(new String[es.size()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a canonical array of String elements from a String
     * that may contain zero or more elements separated by characters in
     * delimiters string.
     *
     * @param elements a String that may contain zero or more
     *        delimiters separated elements.
     * @param delimiters string with delimiters, every character represents one
     *        delimiter.
     * @return the array of elements, each element is trimmed.
     */
    private static String[] getElements(String elements, String delimiters) {
        String regex = "[";
        for(char c : delimiters.toCharArray())
            regex += Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(c));
        regex += "]";

        String[] es = elements.split(regex);
        for (int i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
            es[i] = es[i].trim();
        }
        return es;
    }
}
```